# Apply ng-change to an <input type="file"..>, that already uses it's own Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a validateFormat() function each time an input of type 'file' changes. Note that a custom directive is used 'file-model'

If I try to add 'ng-change="validateFormat()"' to the input, the console prints the following error: no controller: ngModel.

How can I bind this element to ng-change?

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyControllerController">
    <input type="file" file-model="file" />
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    {{error}}
</div>
```

**Angular 1.x**:

```
var module = angular.module("umbraco");

module.controller('OnlineServices.JobCentreUploadController', [
                  '$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope,         
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
      var file = $scope.file;
      var uploadUrl = "/umbraco/api/jc/Upload";
      fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, $scope);
    };
}]);

module.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);

module.service('fileUpload', ['$http', 'notificationsService', function ($http, notificationsService) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
    .success(function () {
        notificationsService.success("Success", "File uploaded successfully.");
    })
    .error(function () {
        notificationsService.error("Error", "File has not been uploaded.");
    });
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-change` directive needs `ng-model` 
Behind the screen `ng-change` sets a watch for the corresponding `ng-model`.

Coming to your problem you are trying to call `ng-change` without specifying `ng-model` on it that is the reason for **error**.

In your custom directive you've created an event handler for `change` event.

So if you want to set up ng-change event for your input element you can do it in your custom directive only no need to go for ng-change directive.

In order to do so you need to pass your `validateFormat` function as paramter to custom directive and execute the function in `change` callback like below:

Example code:

```
element.bind('change', function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
    });
    //Get this function using isolated scope and call it
    validateFormat();
});
```